# Cypress.config().baseUrl point to localhost instead baseURL from cypress.json

Tags: cypress

In Cypress, I have this testing code:

```
describe('In Viewport LARGE 1366', function() {
    it('Google', function() {
        //cy.visit('/');
        cy.log(Cypress.config().baseUrl);
    });
});
```

Cypress configuration is:

```
{
  "baseUrl": "https://www.google.com",
  "viewportWidth": 1300,
  "viewportHeight": 660
}
```

[Cypress.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVUkY.png)

Cypress version: 3.6

When I run the test, Cypress.config().baseUrl is localhost:1313 not google site as I mention in cypress.json

[Running code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Errv.png)

What is the problem ?

PS: with cy.visit('/'); I have the same problem - it points to http://localhost:1313

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was at in *cypress/support/index.js*

**Cypress.config('baseUrl', 'http://localhost:1313/');**

and this overwritten *cypress.json* settings